# Picking out values from pandas DataFrame with mixed delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
df.head()
0    x=2.875,y=-69.625,z=1071.6
1      x=1.625,y=-71.875,z=1071
2     x=5.75,y=-68.625,z=1071.2
3     x=3.75,y=-68.875,z=1072.2
4       x=-1.5,y=-71.625,z=1066
```

I would like to create from this a new DataFrame with the columns x, y, z containing those values. How can I do that? My attempt so far is something like this:

```
d0 = df.str.split(',', n=2, expand=True)
x = d0[0].str.split('=', expand=True)
x.head()
0    2.875
1    1.625
2    5.750
3    3.750
4   -1.500
```

But that gives only one column, and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension for list of dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict([y.split('=') for y in x.split(',')]) for x in df])
print (df1)
       x        y       z
0  2.875  -69.625  1071.6
1  1.625  -71.875    1071
2   5.75  -68.625  1071.2
3   3.75  -68.875  1072.2
4   -1.5  -71.625    1066
```

Comment: This creates some extra columns, `x_count   y_min   z_s2` etc. I added `columns=['x','y','z']` to give only the columns I wanted.